# AFNetworking JSON Response caching: offline mode

Tags: ios, json, caching, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am creating an iOS Application working in **offline mode** by using a `AFNetworking` library.

**To manage a HTTP request** I have defined a `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)requestOperationManager
{
    if (!_requestOperationManager)
    {
        _requestOperationManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SERVICE_BASE_URL]];
    }

    return _requestOperationManager;
}
```

**To load a HTTP request** I have defined a method:

```
- (void)loadRequest
{
    if (!self.internetConnectionAvaliable)
    {
        self.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad;
    }

    NSString *url = SERVICE_METHOD_URL;

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"password" : USER_PASSWORD, @"username" : USER_NAME};

    [self.requestOperationManager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [responseObject objectForKey:@"view"]];

        [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    }

    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR!!!" message:@"ERROR!!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"CANCEL" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alertView show];
    }];
}
```

**When internet connection is enabled**, `AFNetworking` loads desired data perfectly.
**When internet connection is disabled**, `AFNetworking` doesn't load any data. This makes me think, that data caching doesn't work as it should!

Does anyone knows why?
How to fix it?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173839/afnetworking-2-0-and-use-cache-only-when-offline stackoverflow question. It may help you.

Comment: I have been trying to create like this. Sadly, unsuccessfully...

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572050/load-offline-cached-json-using-afnetworking

Comment: Yes I have tried this one.