# AFNetworking caching response of multipart POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, afnetworking-2

I've inherited a project needing to cache the response returned by a multipart POST. We are using AFNetworking 2, up to date to the latest version.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173839/afnetworking-2-0-and-use-cache-only-when-offline), and the [post linked to it](http://www.hpique.com/2014/03/how-to-cache-server-responses-in-ios-apps/), but unfortunately the method used by `AFHTTPSessionManager` to perform a multipart POST, `-POST:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:success:failure:` does not call the ones that the guide suggests to override.

The guide suggests to *enable offline mode* by changing the `cachePolicy` of the request sent used to create the `NSURLSessionDataTask`, and to force caching by modifying the headers of the response. The first is done by overriding the method `AFHTTPSessionManager` calls to create the task, the second by overriding the `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` delegate implementation related with caching.

As said above, neither of those is called. In particular, the method called to get a data task instance is `-uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:progress:completionHandler:` which returns a `NSURLSessionUploadTask`. That I can successfully override and performing the same trick on the `cachePolicy` value.

When it comes to the delegate though, as far as I understand, the library sets a new delegate rather than `self`, `AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate`. This object, despite conforming to `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` does not implement the caching method, and I can't find any way to set a caching callback on it.

Any idea on how to proceed? Any blogpost to point to?

I'm considering overriding the method setting that `AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate`, to provide my own *decorated* subclass, that implements the caching delegate method. Does this make sense?

Thanks